# Using special characters with Search

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

I'm using SearchView (or SearchManager?) to search the database for hits. It works fine, but the problem is if you search for words with special characters (č, ž, š - all supported by the keyboard), the search returns nothing, even though the word exists in the database. 
For example: `Word in database ("Računalnik"); search string ("Rač") - returns 0, search string ("Rac") - returns 0.`
Is there a way to change search encoding, or to handle these searches some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use unicode for those special characters.